# How to get imageView value to insert in to Sqlite?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, android-bitmap

When I click on my button I can select the photo and it shows in my imageView. 
But when I click to save, my imageView has become NULL. Anyone can help me? 
Bitmap always comes null.

I changed

```
Bitmap bitmap =  
((BitmapDrawable)imageViewProeto.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

to

```
Bitmap bitmap = imageViewProeto.getDrawingCache();
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7gcN.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
>
> Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();

To save Image in Your Gallery :

```
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/YourFolderName");
dir.mkdirs();
String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Refresh Gallery :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And Dont Forget to add permission in your Menifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I have changed the answer please try again